# Automated testing of local storage

Tags: testing, local-storage

we recently implemented on our websites local storage. I am curious if there is some way to automate testing of local storage. I don't mean unit test etc. I am looking for some tools from testers perspective for example - possibility to test it with Selenium or other test automation tool.

Thank you